# Decrypt $HOME from Separate Partition after re-install

Tags: filesystem, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

Previously, I had installed 10.10 with three partitions - **sda1-/boot(ext2) sda2-/(btrfs) sda3- /home(btrfs)**. And I have chosen encrypted home folder. Now on same machine I have installed 10.04 (LTS) with choosing new /boot on same sda1, / on same sda2 (ext4) and **sda3(home) left untouched** from earlier install.

My problem is that now I cant access/mount my previous home with **ecryptfs-mount-private**
util with the passphrase of earlier home user. Here is the ERROR: *Encrypted private directory is not setup properly.*
I have also installed btrfs utilities.

So are there any solutions/workarounds to gain access to $home on different partition.

Answer (score 5):

Lucky you! I just had the same problem and wrote a script that will facilitate mounting ecryptfs Folders with FNEK.

```
sudo su -
```

Then open nano/vim/your editor of choice and create a file `ecryptfs-fnek-helper.sh` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Thanks to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/455709
# 

echo "Where is the /home with the .ecryptfs mounted? (default=/mnt/home)"
read home_ecryptfs
if [ -z "$home_ecryptfs" ]; then
    home_ecryptfs=/mnt/home
fi
home_ecryptfs=$home_ecryptfs/.ecryptfs

echo "Whose encrypted home would you like to mount?"
read user
if [ -z "$user" ]; then
    echo "You have to enter a user!"
    exit;
fi

echo "What is the user's password?"
read -s password
if [ -z "$password" ]; then
    echo "You have to enter a password!"
    exit;
fi

echo "Where would you like to mount it? (Default: /mnt/[username])"
read target
if [ -z "$target" ]; then
    target=/mnt/$user
fi
target=$target/
mkdir -p $target

wrapped=$home_ecryptfs/$user/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
sig=$home_ecryptfs/$user/.ecryptfs/Private.sig
private=$home_ecryptfs/$user/.Private/

echo I will be mounting $private into $target.

echo "Clearing the keyring."
keyctl clear @u
keyctl list @u

echo "Unwrapping passphrase and inserting it into key:"
printf "%s" $password | ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring $wrapped -

keyctl list @u

echo -e "\e[0;92mPassphrase:"
echo -e '\e[1;92m'`printf "%s" $password | ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase $wrapped - `'\e[0m'
echo -e "\e[0;96mFilename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature:"
echo -e '\e[1;96m'`tail -n1 $sig`'\e[0m'
echo -e "Mounting now! Be sure to enable FNEK!"
mount.ecryptfs $private $target -o ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,key=passphrase
```

This will unwrap your passphrase and add it to the keyring. It will also display the passhprase and the correct FNEK signature, so you can copy/paste them when prompted by mount.ecryptfs.

Make the file executable and run it while still in su:

```
chmod +x ecryptfs-fnek-helper.sh
./ecryptfs-fnek-helper.sh
```

Comment: Lucky me finding your answer while trying to recover my home files from an Ubuntu laptop drive plugged into my Fedora desktop, your script still works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to decrypt your home directory with the following command:

```
sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek
sudo mount -t ecryptfs /home/username /home/username -o key=passphrase,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=yes
```

If you have not encrypted the file names, remove the passphrase related commands/args. You could find more information about mouting ecryptfs [here](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22mount+-t+ecryptfs%22).
Best Regards.

Comment: Nope. That didnt helped to gain access. It seems it has mounted the same home dir w/o any change. The two files(symlinks) are still there. On both with encryptfs mounted dir and on original dir. Files are - Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop and README.txt

`$ ls  /media/drive/user1/`
`Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop  README.txt`
`$ sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek`
`Passphrase: `
`Inserted auth tok with sig [series of numbers] into the user session keyring`
`Inserted auth tok with sig [series of numbers] into the user session keyring`

Comment: `$ sudo mount -t ecryptfs /media/drive/user1/ /mnt  -o key=passphrase,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=yes
Passphrase: 
Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature  [series of numbers]: [FNEK_given from series]
Attempting to mount with the following options:
  ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
  ecryptfs_fnek_sig=[Given fnek]
  ecryptfs_key_bytes=16
  ecryptfs_cipher=aes
  ecryptfs_sig=[signature]
Mounted eCryptfs
$ ls  /mnt
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop  README.txt`

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/455709
Unfortunately passing the FNEK sig does not work with -o.