# Trying to mount old encrypted home

Tags: ecryptfs

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 10.10 onto a new hard drive and want to mount the old home directory to a subdirectory of my new (also encrypted) home directory.

I tried this with `sudo mount -t ecryptfs /mnt/oldhome/me/ /home/me/oldhome`, with `/mnt/oldhome` being the /home partition of the old system.

Afterwards ~/oldhome contains a desktop link file (Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop) linking to `ecryptfs-mount-private` and a `README.txt` saying I should run `ecryptfs-mount-private`. I do so, but as I don't know what is supposed to happen, I can't tell if it happens and if it brings me closer to accessing my old home.

Any hints?

**update**

I was able to mount my old encrypted home with the help of [this script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31675/decrypt-home-from-separate-partition-after-re-install/34169#34169). Though, looking into it with `ls`, I get alot of errors like this:

```
ls: cannot access /mnt/oldme/some_file: No such file or directory
```

Other information `ls -l` should show, is replaced by question marks.

**update 2**

I mounted the old system to /mnt/oldroot and mount /dev, /sys, /proc and the old home partition into. Then I chrooted into /mnt/oldroot, `su - me` and `ecryptfs-mount-private`. Asked for the passphrase I put it in and got:

```
Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
ERROR: Your passphrase is incorrect
```

`ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` gives me the exact same passphrase I used, though.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you use the [ecryptfs-recover-private](http://manpg.es/ecryptfs-recover-private) utility in these cases.

A full explanation of how to use it is available [here](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html).

Comment: Just an hint to myself because it's the n-th time I have to run this command and every time I have to reverse engineer how it works: the correct syntax to skip the whole-tree file search and crack-open an old home dir, is: `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private --rw .ecryptfs/<YOUR_USER>/.Private`. No need to exhume the 32 bytes long passphrase, just a few attempts to guess the password of that old pc.

Comment: Having some similar yet different issues on a new post (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035424/ubuntu-18-04-mount-encrypted-disk) , do you think you could share your expertise on this? Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes this gives `Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed [-5]` even though the passphrase is correct. As per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285541/mount-no-such-file-or-directory-with-encrypted-recovery/395391#comment878481_395391, it's helpful to run `sudo ecryptfs-manager`, then press 4 (exit), then run `ecryptfs-recover-private` again.

Comment: I did exactly this, and I first thought it did work, as I got "INFO: Success!  Private data mounted at [/tmp/ecryptfs.xxx]." However `ecryptfs-recover-private` seems to mount my *current* home dir also under /tmp/ecryptfs.xxx, but not the one I from my backup I passed to the script. Any idea?

Comment: Ah, found it: there is a symlink from `backup-dir/home/user/.Private` to my current home ...

Answer (score 18):

I finally managed to mount my encrypted home by first adding the passphrase via

```
sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek
```

Which gets me the following information:

```
Inserted auth tok with sig [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa] into the user session keyring
Inserted auth tok with sig [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb] into the user session keyring
```

There, I remember bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb and proceed with mounting the associated .Private directory:

```
sudo mount -t ecryptfs /mnt/oldhome/.ecryptfs/me/.Private /mnt/oldme
```

A lot of questions pop up, which I all answer with their defaults except for

```
Enable filename encryption (y/n) [n]: y
```

and

```
Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]: bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

With bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb, of course, being the signature I previously remembered. Easy, huh?

Comment: Hi @rausch ! Just a clarification question: when you run the first command (ecryptfs-add-passphrase), do you indicate the passphrase from the old or new home/system? And by passprhase you mean the code obtained by ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase or just login? Thanks!!

Comment: a) Old system, and a) the code. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @rausch I noticed in next to my wrapped-passphrase file was a Private.sig file that matched up wit the sig's that you get from ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek. So you can use that to make sure you are typing the right everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /media/<username>/<disk-guid>/home/.ecryptfs/<username>/.Private
```

output if you know the login passphrase:

```
INFO: Found [/media/<username>/<disk.guid>/home/.ecryptfs/<username>/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: 
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] 
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase: 
Inserted auth tok with sig [c67c3e3ace421e76] into the user session keyring
INFO: Success!  Private data mounted at [/tmp/ecryptfs.xblDkqNZ].
```

Last line shows where the decrypted data is mounted

Credits to Santiago G. Marín [on the comments section from this post](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error `ERROR: Failed to mount private data at [/tmp/ecryptfs....]` after I renamed the previous (original) POSIX username to old_user and then created a new user with the original (previous username's) login.

To be able to mount the encrypted home directory from the old_user, I had to remake the symbolik links for .encryptfs and .Private in its folder (as they had poinded to /home/original_name/).

After that, the following command mounted the old home without any problem.

```
/usr/bin/ecryptfs-recover-private /home/old_user/.Private
```

If the above fails because of the key issue (see dmesg or syslog), e.g.

```
Could not find key with description: [XXX]
process_request_key_err: No key Could not find valid key in user session keyring for sig specified in mount option: [XXX]
```

then, try adding the passphrase manually: Option **1** in `/usr/bin/ecryptfs-manager` (it may show you that the key is already there, it's OK.) and then execute `ecryptfs-recover-private /home/old_user/.Private` once again.