# Automatically mount encrypted directory, other than home, on login

Tags: mount, ecryptfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Securely automount encrypted drive at user login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103835/securely-automount-encrypted-drive-at-user-login)

I finally managed to figure out [how to mount an ecryptfs encrypted directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36573/trying-to-mount-old-encrypted-home) (my old home directory)

I would like to have it mounted automatically when I login, the same way my home directory gets mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Add the device to /etc/fstab

It should resemble something like:

/dev/mapper/crypto_test /mnt/crypto_test ext4 defaults 0 2

Comment: How does the passphrase go in there?