# Making the old encrypted /home partition (10.10) available to new install (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, mount, fstab, ecryptfs

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a fresh partition and my old Ubuntu 10.10 has my home directory encrypted. I was wondering if I can mount this home directory as /home/myoldhome in to new install whenever I use it in RW mode.

I already referred  [Trying to mount old encrypted home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36573/trying-to-mount-old-encrypted-home) and was able to use `ecryptfs-recover-private` utility to mount my home directory to  `/tmp/ecryptfs.xxxx`. But this would not help me to access the data in R/w mode and to mount in subsequent boots to 12.04 automatically. Moving the data to new home directory is not an option since I do not have enough hard disk space in the new partition.

By following, the answer 1 from rausch, I could mount the filesystem, but all the files/directories are shown as `ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.xxxx.xxxx`.

So is it possible to mount the encrypted home directory in read/write mode and make an entry to /etc/fstab to automatically mount it every time I boot in to 12.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the man page on ecrypt-recover-private and it has two optional arguments, one of which is --rw which allows you to read and write.