# Mount old encrypted home

Tags: mount, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

I'm aware of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36573/trying-to-mount-old-encrypted-home) post, but my problem is slightly different.

I have two partitions, one with my old Ubuntu 10.04, and one with my current Ubuntu 12.04. My old home is encrypted using ecryptfs, but I'm unsure what password I used when I set it up; the only thing I'm sure of is that I know my previous login password, and that when I log in in my previous Ubuntu, all my data is there.

Now I didn't *forget* that password, I'm just not sure what it is and I'd like to make a few "trials", but I'm not sure if I should begin with the `sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek` right away. My previous login password is different from my current one.

`ecryptfs-mount-private` seems to run in the console, but no `Private` folders shows up in my home then, and I don't get any error message (and no message at all for that matter). When I click on the `Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop` in my old home, I see a console window that opens and shuts down right away.  Finally `ecryptfs-setup-private` returns `ERROR:  wrapped-passphrase file already exists, use --force to overwrite.` which means it's already setup correctly I guess?

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

EDIT:

Now that I think about it, I don't **need** to have these encrypted actually, I guess I just wanted to try out a nice feature of Ubuntu in my previous distro. Since I'm still able to login there, I don't mind "disabling" the encryption altogether if it's simpler than getting this pb fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want ecryptfs-recover-private to "recover  data  from  [your] encrypted  home  or  encrypted private partitions.  It is useful to run this from a LiveISO or a recovery image." It can use your old login passphrase to unwrap your ecrypfs mount passphrase and access your data.

You could also use ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase with your old login passphrase to find out what the ecryptfs mount passphrase is directly.