# /home automatically ecrypted during multi boot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, data-recovery, ecryptfs

I was attempting to add a Mint partition to my Ubuntu 12.04/Win7 box, when the whole process went south on me. Mint installed correctly but removed the Ubuntu/Win options from my Grub menu. Attempting to fix that was where things got messed up -- currently the box boots to a `grub>` prompt.

Using grub I can find a kernal image and boot to a busybox prompt, but if I attempt to continue the boot process, it enters a kernal panic (exit code is `00000200`).

What seems really weird is that my old Ubuntu home folder is accessible if I boot with a Mint or Ubuntu LiveCD (mounted under /media), however my `/home/liav` subdirectory has been ecrypted. I don't recall ever setting up any /home/liav encryption. I can sudo into `/media/home/liav` and cat the README file therein which only says "`THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA"` plus instructions to '`ecryptfs-mount-private`', which I obviously can't do as root in a liveCD session (returns '`Encrypted private directory is not setup properly`'). Using '`chown -R`' to take ownership of the directories made no difference.

- Why was `/home/liav` ecrypted?
- Is there a way I can recreate the user account which would have access to the encrypt keys?

I did do a back up of my main `/home` subdirectory, but would prefer not to lose the dir if possible.

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36573/trying-to-mount-old-encrypted-home?rq=1) question, and I don't think just doing a multi-boot encrypts your home directory. However, when you first installed Ubuntu, I believe there was a checkbox whether or not to encrypt your home directory. I don't remember if it was checked by default or not.

Comment: `ecryptfs-recover-private` did the trick. Thank you saiarcot895. If submit that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can't recover your Ubuntu installation, you can use `ecryptfs-recover-private` to mount your home directory.

First start by making sure that the partition that contains the home directory you want to open is mounted and opened. Then, in a Terminal, run `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /path/to/home/directory`. By default, it will be mounted in read-only mode, but you can have it in read-write mode by passing in the flag `--rw`. Follow the prompts, and your home directory will be mounted in a temporary location.