# Ubuntu 14.04 wont boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, error-handling

After a few months of not using my ubuntu laptop, I decided to use it again. For a few days it was extremely slow, with applications randomly freezing every few minutes, simple commands like ls taking 6-7 seconds, and not being able to locate any packages using apt-get install.

Today, the laptop finally decided to not boot and a block of messages is being produced on tty1. I can log onto tty1 and some commands such as cd seem to be working, but this block of messages is just outputted over and over again every few seconds.

Since I'm on my phone right now and for some reason I cant seem to attach a photo, ill write out the messages continuously being outputted.

ata1.00 exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x20 SErr action 0x0
ata1.00 irq_stat 0x40000008
ata1.00 failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
status {DRDY ERR}
error {UNC}
blk_update_request : I/O error, dev sda, sector 900338152

some numbers do change as the block of message is repeated, but this seems to be the gist of it...

If possible I would like to retain the files on the laptop. Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Thank you

Comment: If you want to just restore your files (if you want to wipe everything), just boot with a Bootable USB of Linux and, from there, access your files by mounting the partition. If your home folder is encrypted, follow [this guide](http://askubuntu.com/a/609151/481256).

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean. Is this a solution for restoring my files or wiping everything? Do these terms go hand in hand? Sorry for my low level understanding

Comment: Booting up through a Bootable USB (i.e. "Try Ubuntu" option) will let you run a version of Ubuntu. From here, you may do anything that a regular Ubuntu PC can do (e.g. copying your home folder to an external hard drive). So that's a solution for restoring your files (or at least backing them up, then reinstalling Ubuntu (if you really have to), then restoring them). From there, feel free to do anything with your "no longer bootable" computer (e.g. reinstall).

Answer (score 0):

Live CD/USB (for example - download Ubuntu Live CD from offical site) is a good way to get your data back. If your file system is corrupted, look onto `testdisk`.