# How to automatically specify the Filename Encryption Key with ecryptfs?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, luks

When mounting a ecryptfs encrypted folder, I have the question,

```
Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature [d3f92227db598fd6]:
```

I want to automatically answer to this question, and it is done with the option ecryptfs_sig=(fekek_sig) (see `man ecryptfs`)

However, I don't but I don't know what should be the argument.

**What is the argument that should be given to `ecryptfs_sig` to automatically chose the `FNEK`?**

My guess is that I should add a key with `ecryptfs-add-passphrase`.

---

PS:

From `man ecryptfs`:

```
   ecryptfs_sig=(fekek_sig)
                 Specify the signature of the mount wide authentication token. The authentication token must be in the kernel keyring before the mount is performed. ecryptfs-
                               manager or the eCryptfs mount helper can be used to construct the authentication token and add it to the keyring prior to mounting.
```

The automated expression I already have:

```
mount -t ecryptfs,key=passphrase,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_passthrough,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=y,no_sig_cache $FOLDER $FOLDER
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is rigtht; you must run `ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek`; the option for `mount` is `ecryptfs_fnek_sig=<fnek_sig>`. See the answer to the question [How do I mount an eCryptFS encrypted partition on login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695705/how-do-i-mount-an-ecryptfs-encrypted-partition-on-login) under the heading "This script does work".