# Cannot mount old encrypted home directory

Tags: mount, ecryptfs

I host my `home` directory on a hard drive separate from the rest of the Ubuntu install. I recently got a new drive and I'm in the process of migrating my user data from the old drive to the new one.

The problem is: I used ecryptfs to encrypt my user's home directory and now I can't mount the old encrypted directory. I am aware of [this similar thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36573/trying-to-mount-old-encrypted-home), and I've attempted to use the `ecryptfs-recover-private` command as suggested, but I get the following error (updated with the output of `dmsg`):

```
jrsmith3@hermes:~$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private || sudo dmesg -T | tail -n 5
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
INFO: Found [/mnt/.ecryptfs/jrsmith3/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: 
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] 
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase: 
Inserted auth tok with sig [154a85415793937b] into the user session keyring
mount: No such file or directory
ERROR: Failed to mount private data at [/tmp/ecryptfs.HUXQDUjB].
[Sun Dec  6 10:21:34 2015] Could not find key with description: [a798123c6b6e6b59]
[Sun Dec  6 10:21:34 2015] process_request_key_err: No key
[Sun Dec  6 10:21:34 2015] Could not find valid key in user session keyring for sig specified in mount option: [a798123c6b6e6b59]
[Sun Dec  6 10:21:34 2015] One or more global auth toks could not properly register; rc = [-2]
[Sun Dec  6 10:21:34 2015] Error parsing options; rc = [-2]
```

I suspect the problem may not be with ecryptfs; it looks like the error is occuring with the `mount` command, but I can't figure it out.

I'm running Ubuntu:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's great, but unfortunately, I can't make anything of it. My hope was, that the issue lied in the mount process, not key management. Looking at the key identifiers, it seems, that the inserted and requested keys are different.

Comment: It's weird because I can unwrap the key with my login password, and the key matches what was generated when I originally encrypted my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try stepping through the `ecryptfs-recover-private` script yourself? It's just a bash script, you can copy & paste relevant lines into a terminal, replacing variables with your actual files.

You can also copy the `ecryptfs-recover-private` script and modify it, adding some extra echo lines to see what variables are before mounting, echo lines to be run, etc. (I'm certain there's a bash setting to display every line before it's run, but can't remember it right now.)

Maybe the `ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring` or the `.ecryptfs/Private.sig` signatures aren't matching, though the script checks for that.... but your output inserts one key sig, and tries mounting with a different sig.

At least you could run mount with `-v` for a little more feedback and to verify that the folders and sigs are correct.

There's also a bug, I thought just in `mount.ecryptfs` but maybe showing up here, where the fnek & fekek sigs get switched somehow.

Or, maybe some files have been corrupted. Any `fsck` news, or a current backup may be required. Also `/var/log/syslog` could have even more info.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will step through the `ecryptfs-recover-private` script and see where the failure is.

Comment: I'd look closely at the key sigs, appears to insert key sig 154a85415793937b but tries mounting with sig a798123c6b6e6b59. Edited in an idea to copy & edit (add "debug" echos, etc) the recover script

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error `ERROR: Failed to mount private data at [/tmp/ecryptfs....]` after I renamed the previous (original) POSIX username to old_user and then created a new user with the original (previous username's) login.

To be able to mount the encrypted home directory from the old_user, I had to remake the symbolik links for .encryptfs and .Private in its folder (as they had poinded to /home/original_name/).

After that, the following command mounted the old home without any problem.

```
/usr/bin/ecryptfs-recover-private /home/old_user/.Private
```

If the above fails because of the key issue (see dmesg or syslog), e.g.

```
Could not find key with description: [XXX]
process_request_key_err: No key Could not find valid key in user session keyring for sig specified in mount option: [XXX]
```

then, try adding the passphrase manually: Option **1** in `/usr/bin/ecryptfs-manager` (it may show you that the key is already there, it's OK.) and then execute `ecryptfs-recover-private /home/old_user/.Private` once again.
If it still gives you an error, try this command:

```
ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring /home/old_user/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```