# How to recover an encrypted directory from a live distribution?

Tags: live-usb, encryption, data-recovery, ecryptfs

After my motherboard has been changed, the system does not start any more. I think I will have to re-install, but in this case, I am affraid that the encrypted dir will not mount at login any more (will it?)

So, I am trying to first recover my home, using a live distribution. I have tried to follow advices from StackExchange and elsewhere (e.g. [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/)) but:

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
```

only says:

```
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
find: ‘/run/user/999/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: File system loop detected; ‘/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/sys/kernel/debug’.
```

So I tried to give the directory path:

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private '/media/ubuntu-gnome/<UUID>/username'
```

After entering the passphrase, I obtained a 'success' message, saying the decrypted directory was mounted in '/tmp/ecryptfs.SOMETHING' but this directory contained:

```
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop
README.txt
.ecryptfs
.Private
```

I guess this means it is not recovered. Then, trying again the same command resulted in failure with:

```
mount: mount(2) failed: No such file or directory
ERROR: Failed to mount private data at [/tmp/ecryptfs.SOMETHINGELSE].
```

OK, maybe I made a mistake in the passphrase, but I tried several times...

Additional information: my home is at the root of a disk having one partition, the system is on another disk. Exploring the data disk with nautilus shows:

```
<UUID>
 +-- username
       +-- Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop
       +-- README.txt
       +-- .ecryptfs
       +-- .Private
 +-- .ecryptfs
       +-- username
             +-- .ecryptfs
                   +-- auto-mount
                   +-- auto-umount
                   +-- Private.mnt
                   +-- Private.sig
                   +-- wrapped-passphrase
                   +-- .wrapped-passphrase.recorded
             +-- .Private
```

In particular, I am surprised to find:

```
/media/ubuntu-gnome/<UUID>/.ecryptfs/username/.ecryptfs
```

Is this a normal structure?

**EDIT** The answer was just a couple of pages away:

see the answer by @rausch the life saver to 
[Trying to mount old encrypted home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36573/trying-to-mount-old-encrypted-home/36783#36783)

And, by the way, my directory structure was normal.